# Proving directly that $S \otimes_A M = 0$ iff $Sf(\mathrm{ann} M) = S$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $f\colon A \to S$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings and $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module.  Some standard definitions:
$$\mathrm{supp} \ M = \{\mathfrak p \leq A \ \text{prime} \ | \ M_{\mathfrak p} \neq 0\},$$
$$\mathrm{ann} \ M = \{a \in A \ | \ aM = 0\},$$
$$V(I) = \{\mathfrak p \leq A \ \text{prime} \ | \ I \subseteq \mathfrak p\}.$$
Now it's not too hard to show (it's essentially 2 exercises in Atiyah-Macdonald) that considering $S \otimes_A M$ as an $S$-module we get
$$\mathrm{supp}(S \otimes_A M) = V(S\cdot f(\mathrm{ann} \ M))$$
Since being $0$ is a local property we conclude that $S \otimes_A M = 0$ if and only if $S\cdot f(\mathrm{ann} \ M)) = S$.  I'd like to know if it's possible to prove this fact directly without resorting to geometric arguments (specifically, avoiding localization if possible, or minimizing it's use if complete avoidance is too hard).

The direction $S\cdot f(\mathrm{ann} \ M)) = S \Rightarrow S \otimes_A M = 0$ is obvious.  The other direction should only be true for finitely generated $M$ suggesting an induction on the number of generators.  Modules of the form $M = A/\mathfrak a$ give $S \otimes_A M \simeq S/(S\cdot f(\mathfrak a))$ so the base case is easy.  For the inductive step you can take a short exact sequence
$$0 \to M' \to M \to M/M' \to 0$$
where the statement is known to hold for the modules $M'$ and $M/M'$.  Then assuming $S \otimes_A M = 0$ gives $S \otimes_A M/M' = 0$ so $S\cdot f(\mathrm{ann} \ M/M')) = S$.  I think this and $\mathrm{ann} \ M = \mathrm{ann} \ M' \cap \mathrm{ann} \ M/M'$ give you $S\cdot f(\mathrm{ann} \ M) = S\cdot f(\mathrm{ann} \ M')$ but $S \otimes_A M'$ needn't be zero so I'm stuck.  Can anyone see how to finish the argument or is this idea doomed?

Comment: $\mathrm{ann} \ M = \mathrm{ann} \ M' \cap \mathrm{ann} \ M/M'$ is wrong.

Comment: Oops, I think I fixed all the $B, R$ issues.  Is the intersection wrong?  Is it supposed to be the product $\mathrm{ann} \ M = (\mathrm{ann} \ M')(\mathrm{ann} \ M/M')$ instead?

Comment: Not at all! (Try some simple examples.)

Comment: Ahh, yea I was forgetting the radicals, it's $\mathrm{rad}(\mathrm{ann} \ M) = \mathrm{rad}(\mathrm{ann} \ M' \cap \mathrm{ann} \ M/M')$.  Unfortunately this doesn't help at all in the proof...